# Getting a MongooseServerSelectionError when trying to connect to MongoDB in WSL2 using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i am new to wsl and programming.. i use wsl 2 and windows 11. node.js version is v20.2.0
MongoDB:  6.0.6
Mongosh: 1.9.1

my code is simple and very basic i wanted to start mongoose for the first time in wsl using vscode
[my entire code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al5PX.png)

I make sure the mongo server was running by using `sudo systemctl status mongod`[active services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDIfc.png)

This is the code

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongoDb = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shopDB"

const app = express();

mongoose.connect(mongoDb);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
})
```

i got output

```
Server is running on port 3000
/home/tanjiro/Programming/WebD/MongoDb/fruitsDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:792
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/home/tanjiro/Programming/WebD/MongoDb/fruitsDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/home/tanjiro/Programming/WebD/MongoDb/fruitsDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:767:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:540:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      '127.0.0.1:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: '127.0.0.1:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 971788,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (/home/tanjiro/Programming/WebD/MongoDb/fruitsDB/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/tanjiro/Programming/WebD/MongoDb/fruitsDB/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:626:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:511:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1571:16) {
            errno: -111,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v20.2.0
```

[this is my filesystem for the express app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2WUP.png)

when nothing worked i even stopped windows mongo services and tried to only run mongo server in wsl and it got connected with the mongodb compass but then also my code gave same error.

i have spend 4 hours searching on the for the solution trying everything

1. reinstalling everything(including wsl2).
2. swapping localhost to 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0
3. restarting wsl mongo server as well as windows mongo server.

i am in my learning phase and was looking forward to learn databases for backend but this has stopped me and i cannot go forward. Please help me with this issue... Thanks in advance. peace